# Lamda Link type arguments cannot be inferred from usage

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

we are using entity and I am trying to join 2 tables on 2 columns.  an id and server id.  My original query didn't account for server (which is what i'm trying to fix)

```
var client = _Context.Address
                .Join(_Context.Clients.Where(c => c.Key == Key),
                    a => a.AddressId,
                    c => c.AddressId,
                    (a, c) =>  a ).FirstOrDefault();
```

and this works.  But when I add in the server

```
var client = _Context.Address
                .Join(_Context.Clients.Where(c => c.Key == Key),
                    a => new { a.AddressId, a.ServerId},
                    c => new { c.AddressId, c.ServerId},
                    (a, c) =>  a ).FirstOrDefault();
```

the join now throws the error in the title.  In my research I see that the names and types have to match.  The names do match and ive tried assigning them to be doubly sure but that doesn't resolve the issue.  Looking at the definition in entity the columns are int in the address table but are nullable int in the client table.
How can I join an int column to an nullable int?

edit:
from the client table

```
public int? AddressId { get; set; }

public int? ServerId { get; set; }
```

from the address table

```
[Key]   
[Column(Order = 0)]      
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]   
public int AddressId { get; set; }

[Key]
[Column(Order = 1)]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ServerId { get; set; }
```

Comment: both addressid and serverid are nullable in the client table

Comment: Show your Address and Client C# side entities

Comment: *The names do match* - the compiler doesn't care/it wouldn't cause this error, though it would cause the two anonymous types to be inequal at runtime

Comment: fields added in the edit.  both are int.  they are just nullable in one of the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I join an int column to an nullable int?

You need to make them the same type, otherwise the compiler won't be able to decide what TKey is supposed to be because there isn't an implicit conversion between `AnonType<int, int>` and `AnonType<int?, int?>` e.g. cast the non-nullable ints to be `(int?)` so they match

```
Join(_Context.Clients.Where(c => c.Key == Key),
  a => new { AddressId = (int?)a.AddressId, ServerId = (int?)a.ServerId},
  c => new { c.AddressId, c.ServerId},
```

You got away with it before because there was an implicit conversion from `int` to `int?` for the single key argument, but it would have similarly errored if you'd used anonymous types with a single prop in your join keys:

```
//this would fail too
Join(_Context.Clients.Where(c => c.Key == Key),
  a => new { AddressId }, 
  c => new { c.AddressId },
```

Comment: That did it.  thank you!